# Type-theoretic strategies for encoding the notion of an even integer given an evenness predicate and an integer type

Tags: type-theory

A type is loosely analogous to a set. Pushing on this analogy a bit, I'm wondering what the equivalent of the [axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) is.

In particular, I'm curious what strategies are available (i.e. what approaches different type systems take) for encoding something like an even integer given an predicate that assesses evenness and an integer type.

---

Here's a rough attempt to produce some intro and elimination rules for such a concept. These rules are just intended to demonstrate approximately what I'm after. The box construction has some serious rough edges, like throwing away the proof that $p(a) = 1$ and promoting $p$ to the type level without a well-thought-out explanation of what this means.

Given $p : t \to 2$ and $a : t $ and $\tau : p(a) = 1$, we can conclude the following.

$$ \mathrm{box}(a, p) : \mathrm{Box}(t, p) $$

And we can eliminate an instance of type $\mathrm{Box}(\cdots)$ by projecting.

We can remove the box and grab the term.

$$ \pi_1 : \mathrm{Box}(t, p) \to t $$

We can also grab the predicate we used.

$$ \pi_2 : \mathrm{Box}(t, p) \to (t \to 2) $$

The idea is, in this setting, I would be able to define an ordinary $\mathrm{isEven}: \mathbb{Z} \to 2$ function and then use $\mathrm{Box}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathrm{isEven})$ to encode the notion of an even integer.

I'm curious what the real construction is that achieves this. I've heard of the notion of a [dependent pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#%CE%A3_type) before, but I'm not sure how to use it to encode something as boring and routine as an even integer (and don't really understand it).

Comment: If you believe in propositions-as-types then $\sum_{a : t} p (a)$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: i might be misunderstanding, but it sounds like you might be after [refinement types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_type)?